# Domino 9 has a new boolean converter for checkbox group controls - anyone get this working?

Tags: xpages

I added the new boolean converter to a checkbox and bound this to a number field on the Domino form.  When I view the XPage I get an error:  Exception
java.lang.String incompatible with java.lang.Boolean.

My source is

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup
        id="checkBoxGroup1"
        value="#{document1.Good}"
        defaultValue="true">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertBoolean></xp:convertBoolean>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = ["true", "false"];
return arr;}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Just wondering how this new feature in ND9 works???

Comment: Paul Calhoun and Kathy Brown discussed how it's stored as a string since we have no boolean fields in Notes documents in their video on Whats' New in Notes 9 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIRGt5BEhGI

Answer (score 0):

Howard I posted a tip on this here: http://xpagetips.blogspot.com/2013/01/before-ibm-connect-5-days-5-tips-tip-1.html.

I think you're right.  It is only there to make it easier work with boolean values but does not enable actually storing that data type in a Notes document.

Perhaps there is object storage coming in our future??